# IQ time domain data to Constellation regeneration for a OFDM 16 QAM signal at different power levels to obtain EVM vs Pout information

Tags: ofdm, demodulation

16 QAM OFDM signal at output of Power amplifier at fixed frequency and different input power levels are received as a IQ data (time domain) by Spectrum analyzer, I would like to generate 16 QAM constellation at each input power level to evaluate the EVM vs output power information.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: so, you need to build an OFDM receiver. Can you tell us where you're stuck with that?

Comment: I am newbie and basically a RF engineer with limited communication background and skills. Considering this in mind, could you please assist the steps. Happy to listen suggested readings/videos for the steps would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't think that fits the scope of a single answer here. You will need to learn how OFDM works, why it is used, and how a receiver looks like. After you've done that amount of reading, I'm sure your questions will be much more specific, and we could actually write answers that benefit you. What you ask here is just for us to write a digital communications textbook for you, but these have already been written, and better so than what we could write in an answer. I'm also pretty sure that if generating an evm analysis, it's actually expected of you to learn about OFDM. Sadly, no shortcuts!